# Derby Schema Error

Tags: java, database, schema, derby

I am trying to *insert data into Derby embedded database* for my Desktop Application. But Derby is giving me error of **Schema Not found error**. 
I have tried to solve error by creating schema as per username, but does not solve my problem. I searched internet, but none of given solution solved my problem.

```
package derbyd.ui;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class AddStudent extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private void bt_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String conURL = "jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true";
    String user = "SOURABH";
    String passwd = "pass";
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    String query;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL, user, passwd);
        st = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        query = "INSERT INTO SOURABH.MyTable VALUES('"+txt_name.getText()+"','"+txt_surname.getText()+"')";
        st.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Added Successfully");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error ->"+e);
    }
}                                       


}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Frequently Asked Questions](http://db.apache.org/derby/faq.html) of Apache Derby, you will see that:

> A schema is only created by `CREATE SCHEMA` or creating an object (table etc.) in that schema (this is implicit schema creation).

In your code, you need create the table first and then work like a charm.

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL, user, passwd);
st = con.createStatement();
System.out.println("Connection established");

st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE MyTable" +
        "(name VARCHAR(255), surname varchar(255))");
System.out.println("Table created");

query = "INSERT INTO SOURABH.MyTable VALUES(" +
        "'" + txt_name.getText() + "','" + txt_surname.getText() + "')";
st.executeUpdate(query);
System.out.println("Added Successfully");
```

The output is:

```
Connection established
Table created
Added Successfully
```

If you run this statement more than once, you'll get an error because the table already exists. To deal with that, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5866339/870248).

Answer (score 1):

the easiest solution is to configure your database properties and make schema the same as user name but in capital litters
ex:
schema APP
user   app

hope my answer can help.