# How to avoid or ignore SQLExceptions by schema.sql at Spring Boot app startup

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, derby

I have a Spring Boot application that has an embedded in-memory Derby DB and `schema.sql` is executed by Spring Boot at startup.

schema.sql:

```
create schema demo;
create table users (id varchar(10) primary key, name varchar(30), password varchar(30), mail varchar(100));
insert into users (id, name) values ('admin','admin');
```

I wanted to introduce `spring-boot-devtools` to automatically reload changes in my application, so I added the dependency to pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However, the above SQLs causes SQLExceptions and fails to reload because the schema and table has already exist.

So I tried to add the following SQLs, but `if exists`clause cannot be used in Derby.

```
drop schema if exists demo;
drop table if exists users;
```

Could anyone tell me the solution (alternative SQLs or how to ignore the SQL exceptions)?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866154/how-to-create-table-if-it-doesnt-exist-using-derby-db

Comment: I want to know how to catch SQLException and ignore it in manner of Spring Boot.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37690374/2310289 - would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can fix by adding the following property:

```
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

It can ignore SQLExceptions and reload changes in my application.

Answer (score 1):

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.username=app
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

see full worked example here: https://github.com/daggerok/spring-boot-derby-create-drop-example

output ot devtools reload:

```
...
2017-08-09 05:34:07.591  WARN 2728 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 10000, SQLState: 01J01
2017-08-09 05:34:07.592  WARN 2728 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Database 'memory:testdb' not created, connection made to existing database instead.
...
```

Comment: Can this property apply when JPA (and Hibernate) is not used?

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA, I updated answer, added link to example. check it for details

Comment: `schema.sql` in `src/main/resources` folder contains only DDL, `import.sql` contains all DML

Comment: `Can this property apply when JPA (and Hibernate) is not used?`
what do you mean? jdbc?

Comment: I only use Spring JDBC.

Comment: Thank you, @Maksim Kostromin. I have fixed.