# Derby foreign key constraint

Tags: java, foreign-keys, derby, sqlexception

What's the problem with this statement that gives me the following exception?

```
    s.addBatch("CREATE TABLE category ( id  SMALLINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY \n" +
            "\t(START WITH 0, INCREMENT BY 1), title  VARCHAR(100))\n" );
    s.addBatch("CREATE TABLE task (id SMALLINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY \n" +
            "\t(START WITH 0, INCREMENT BY 1), title VARCHAR(100), cat_id INT, visible BOOLEAN, " +
            "deprecated BOOLEAN" +
            "CONSTRAINT fk_cat_id FOREIGN KEY (cat_id)\n" +
            "\tREFERENCES category(id))");
    s.executeBatch();
```

the first addBatch is commented in my running code because I'd created the table before. In fact if I don't comment the first batch I get an error saying that the table already exists and seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866154/how-to-create-table-if-it-doesnt-exist-using-derby-db) I know it's the only way to check if a table exists in derby. I see that my statement is correct according to [this documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html#rrefsqlj13590)

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Syntax error: Encountered "fk_cat_id" at line 2, column 119.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newBatchUpdateException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeLargeBatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
    at model.DBConnection.createTables(DBConnection.java:48)
    at model.DBConnection.<init>(DBConnection.java:33)
    at model.DBConnection.<clinit>(DBConnection.java:10)
    at test.DBTest.main(DBTest.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "fk_cat_id" at line 2, column 119.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeBatchElement(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Encountered "fk_cat_id" at line 2, column 119.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "fk_cat_id" at line 2, column 119.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: There's nothing that separates  `"deprecated BOOLEAN" +` from `"CONSTRAINT fk_cat_id FOREIGN KEY (cat_id)\n"`, so it concatenates as `BOOLEANCONSTRAINT`. Try putting a space after `BOOLEAN `.

Comment: Ah! You're right. However I found more errors and I posted the correct code as an answer.@PM77-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors in the sql statement!

- No primary key is defined for the category.
- The type of id in `category` and `cat_id` in task don't match.
- As `PM77-1` has noted the spaces aren't respected.

Anyway the working code is the following:

```
s.addBatch("CREATE TABLE category ( id  INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY \n" +
        "\t(START WITH 0, INCREMENT BY 1), title  VARCHAR(100), " +
        "\tCONSTRAINT category_pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id))\n" );
s.addBatch("CREATE TABLE task (id SMALLINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY \n" +
        "\t(START WITH 0, INCREMENT BY 1), title VARCHAR(100), cat_id INT, visible BOOLEAN, " +
        "deprecated BOOLEAN," +
        "\t CONSTRAINT task_pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)," +
        "\t CONSTRAINT fk_cat_id FOREIGN KEY (cat_id)\n" +
        "\t REFERENCES category(id))");
```

But there will still be an error in the code that these operations aren't atomic and if one happens and the next goes wrong the first isn't rolled back. It is not unsolved.

Comment: Wrap them all in a [`Transaction`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop63.html)?