# Assigning Foreign Keys in Java DB

Tags: database, javadb

Does Java DB (Derby) as set up in NetBeans allow the use of foreign keys.  If so then how do you designate a particular column as a foreign key?  It seems strange to me that when setting up a table's column there is a checkbox for clicking if there is a primary key but not a checkbox for clicking foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a primary key on the main table so, its key can be used to refer to the foreign constraint.
See this thread. [Derby foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821397/derby-foreign-key-constraint)